# iOS 9: UIPresentationController::runTransitionForCurrentState is not called when home button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, uipresentationcontroller

I'm a newbee in iOS development and would be really appreciative if anyone could help me with this problem.

It seems that in iOS <= 8 `UIPresentationController::runTransitionForCurrentState` is called when home button is pressed but that doesn't happen in iOS 9, which causes some issues in my app. I was wondering what is the reason behind the scene. Is it a bug of iOS 9? If so, are there any work around solutions to solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to achieve? The method you mentioned in your question is not part of any public API. So you never can rely on the private methods, because Apple can change them at any time.

Maybe you try to explain what you are actually trying to solve. Maybe we can come up with a better solution then.

Cheers
Orlando

Answer (score -1):

I guess I had the same issue with presentation controller.
I'm presenting view controller with presentViewController:animated:completion: but it is presented only when I tap on the screen. 
It seems like events is waiting in a queue to perform.
So I just execute presentation in dispatch_async block and It works.